# Python Name Error. Name is not defined while using Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, lemmatization

First of all I'm new to Python. what I'm trying to do is to lemmatize my data from a CSV. Used pandas to read the csv.
But while running this I am getting an error on the line lemmatized.append(**temp**). It's saying *NameError: name 'temp' is not defined*
I can't figure out what is causing this error. I am using python 2.7.
I will be grateful if anyone of you python expert could help me out with this simple problem and thus help me in learning.

```
data = pd.read_csv('TrainingSETNEGATIVE.csv')
list = data['text'].values


def get_pos_tag(tag):
    if tag.startswith('V'):
        return 'v'
    elif tag.startswith('N'):
        return 'n'
    elif tag.startswith('J'):
        return 'a'
    elif tag.startswith('R'):
        return 'r'
    else:
        return 'n'


lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
with open('new_file.csv', 'w+', newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for doc in list:
        tok_doc = nltk.word_tokenize(doc)
        pos_tag_doc = nltk.pos_tag(tok_doc)
        lemmatized = []
        for i in range(len(tok_doc)):
            tag = get_pos_tag(pos_tag_doc[i][1])
            if tag == 'r':
                if tok_doc[i].endswith('ly'):
                    temp = tok_doc[i].replace("ly", "")
            else:
                temp = lemmatizer.lemmatize(tok_doc[i], pos=tag)
            lemmatized.append(temp)
        lemmatized = " ".join(lemmatized)
        wr.writerow([lemmatized])
        print(lemmatized)
```

Screentshot:
[image]

Comment: If ``tag == 'r'`` returns True, but ``tok_doc[i].endswith('ly')`` returns False, then ``temp`` will never be defined. I suspect that's what's causing the error.

Comment: Yes that is the reason. Thanks you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Exception says it all: "name 'temp' is not defined". So the variable `temp` is not defined before it is used.

The problem with your code is here:

```
if tag == 'r':
    if tok_doc[i].endswith('ly'):
        temp = tok_doc[i].replace("ly", "")
    # else: temp = None
else:
    temp = lemmatizer.lemmatize(tok_doc[i], pos=tag)
lemmatized.append(temp)
```

If `tag == 'r'` is True and `tok_doc[i].endswith('ly')` is not `True` then `temp` never gets defined.

Consider adding an `else` clause like the one I inserted and commented out.